# Why is my python word counting program not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm doing a python course and one of the questions asks me to write a program that counts words like this:

```
Enter line: which witch
Enter line: is which
Enter line: 
is 1
which 2
witch 1
```

The code i have so far is:

```
occurences = {}

line = input('Enter line: ')
while line:
  m = line.split()
  for i in m:
    if i in occurences:
      occurences[i] += 1
    else:
      occurences[i] = 1
    line = input('Enter line: ')


for word in sorted(occurences):
  print(word, occurences[word])
```

But when I run this code, it either tells me every word occured only once or some other strange output. Thanks for the help!

Here is an example of it not working:

```
Enter line: test test test
Enter line: one two test
Enter line: one
Enter line: 
test 3
```

This is the output i get while the expected output is:

```
test 4
two 1
one 2
```

Comment: @Bazingaa `i` will be each word in the split input.

Comment: The code looks okay. How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you provide a sample input that does not work for you?

Comment: The code works, but FYI collections.Counter would provide a neater way to do this

Comment: check the indentation of the input line inside while loop, is that correct one ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I wouldn't suggest jumping that far ahead, though.

Comment: @icedwater Maybe not for a beginner (like the OP I assume) but if someone else finds this question one day they should be aware of this more pythonic alternative

Comment: I've upvoted your comment because of this, and because recommending interesting libraries is useful to other people, but yes, it might be violating the prime directive a little too much for newbie questions.

Comment: @blhsing i have added an example in the post.

Comment: Your indentation means it asks for new input for every word in the split line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input inside for loop is causing the problem, please try this:

```
occurences = {}

line = input('Enter line: ')
while line:
  m = line.split()
  print( m)
  for i in m:

    if i in occurences:
      occurences[i] += 1
    else:
      occurences[i] = 1

    print(occurences)
  line = input('Enter line: ')


for word in sorted(occurences):
  print(word, occurences[word])
```

By resetting the input inside the for loop, you are asking for new input after the first word is counted, and ignoring the subsequent words in the string.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue.

Answer (score -1):

When i ran the code i got no output at all, this is because you have a infinite loop by asking the user for another line at the end of the "While" loop, which cause it to do indefinitely.

To match what you were doing before I've changed your code a tiny bit

```
occurences = {}
line = input('Enter line: ')

while line:
    m = line.split()
    for i in m:
        if i in occurences:
            occurences[i] += 1
        else:
            occurences[i] = 1
    break ## Once the word has been put into occurences it breaks
          ##    so that the next loop can run  


for word in sorted(occurences):
    print(word, occurences[word])
```

if you want it to go forever until the user quits the program then you would do this:

```
while True:
    occurences = {}
    line = input('Enter line: ')

    while line:
        m = line.split()
        for i in m:
            if i in occurences:
                occurences[i] += 1
            else:
                occurences[i] = 1
        break

    for word in sorted(occurences):
        print(word, occurences[word])
```

Comment: I think you'll find that it works without the `break`. I'm not sure where you had the infinite loop, I didn't see any.

Comment: @icedwater In his original code the occurrences is printed AFTER the loop puts them into the dict, and the while loop runs aslong as line has text and as he keeps asking for the text it will keep going, now that i look again the break isnt needed just need to remove the input

Comment: I ran the original code, and there was no infinite loop. Once the user presses Enter, submitting an empty string, then the loop ends.